# How can I convert this string into an array of objects using Node JS and Python?

Tags: python, node.js, json, string, sorting

Hi am receiving the following string from a python script:

```
['https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocidad_de_la_luz', 'https://www.endesa.com/es/blog/blog-de-endesa/luz/cuanto-es-velocidad-luz']
['https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number', 'https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%BAmero_primo']
['https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matem%C3%A1ticas', 'https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matem%C3%A1ticas#Introducci%C3%B3n']
```

This is from a google search using googlesearch library:

```
import sys
import json
from googlesearch import search

data2 = json.loads(sys.argv[1])
datasearch = []
results = []

for x in data2:
    datasearch.append(x['questiontext'])
for query in datasearch:
    results.append(search(query, tld="com", num=5, stop = 2, pause = 2))
    
for result in results:
    print(list(result))
```

As you can see each array has 2 links and I would like to access each link. However, this seems to be an array of strings and I am not able to iterate as I would like to.

This is what I have try to convert into an array with no success:

```
Patricia.dataforClient = (questions, dataFromPython) => {
    var questionarray = JSON.parse(questions);
    var newArray = []
    console.log(dataFromPython)
    var links = dataFromPython.split("'");

    console.log(links)
    console.log(links.length)
  
    for (let i = 0; i < questionarray.length; i++) {
        newArray[i] = {
            "pregunta" : questionarray[i]['questiontext'],
            "links" : links[i]
        }
    }

    var newquestions = JSON.stringify(newArray);
    var finaldata = JSON.parse(newquestions);

    return finaldata
}
```

I am only getting something like this (I can iterate through this but still has so many unnecessary characters:

```
[ '[',
  'https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocidad_de_la_luz',
  'https://www.endesa.com/es/blog/blog-de-endesa/luz/cuanto-es-velocidad-luz',
  ']\r\n[',
  'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number',
  ', ',
  'https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%BAmero_primo',
  ']\r\n[',
  'https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matem%C3%A1ticas',
  ', ',
  'https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matem%C3%A1ticas#Introducci%C3%B3n',
  ']\r\n' ]
```

This is what I would like to be able to iterate through, each link of each array:

```
['https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocidad_de_la_luz','https://www.endesa.com/es/blog/blog-de-endesa/luz/cuanto-es-velocidad-luz']
['https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number','https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%BAmero_primo']
['https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matem%C3%A1ticas','https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matem%C3%A1ticas#Introducci%C3%B3n']
```

Comment: Kindly let us know what result are you expecting? Give an example.

Comment: My apologies @DineshPandikona, I have updated the question with the expected result.